# Can we call private methods of abstract class using reflection?

Tags: java, oop, reflection, abstract-class

Can we call private methods of abstract class using reflection?

Comment: you need an instance to be able to call a method (weather by reflection or directly, unless it is a static method)... abstract class can not be instantiated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple test that can be ran by OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you can.**
You can use *reflection*.
What you need -

> 1. The class object of Abstract Class.
> 2. dynamically set the method's accessibility to *true*. Check the code below.

```
class ExitPuzzle extends MyAbstractClass {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class clazz = MyAbstractClass.class;
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(methods));
        methods[0].setAccessible(true);
        methods[0].invoke(new ExitPuzzle(), null);
    }

}

abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    private void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("in MyAbstractClass");
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
[private void MyAbstractClass.myMethod()]
in MyAbstractClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an instance of a `concrete class` which extends the abstract class or you should create an `anonymous inner class instance` for the abstract class(and override the methods marked abstract).You can then use that instance and make the method accessible by making `setAccessible(true)`.This will work unless you mess up with the `SecurityManager`(inmost cases you wont).Then you can invoke the method

Answer (score 0):

**yes you can.**

but you will need an object that is an instance of the abstract class for this.

Comment: you cant. you will need something non abstract that extends the abstract class